# Programatically determine if access token is a Page Access Token or User Access Token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

At the moment, I am trying to download dark posts from the /{user-id}/promotable_posts edge. From the documentation, I can download them using a user token with the ads_management permission or with a page access token.

I am able to check for the permission using the /debug_token node, but I need a way to determine if an access token is a page access token using code/api calls.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by GET `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/debug_token?input_token={access_token}&access_token={access_token}`. If it is a page, response will contains `profile_id` which is the page id